# HTTPS API works ok in Anypoint Studio and not in Runtime standalone Engine - Returns 503 service unavailable

Tags: mule, runtime, anypoint-studio

I have exported my mule application from any point studio and placed it in stand alone mule run time /apps folder . when i start the run time using mule .bat my apps got deployed success fully but when i try to access the api's it gives 503, which is service unavailable .

But the same project if i deploy it through any point studio it got deployed successful and i was able to access the api's through post man and i am getting success response too .

any body can help me to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It probably is the gatekeeper not being able to unlock the API because the standalone Mule Runtime has not the right credentials. See https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/API-returns-503-Service-Unavailable-error-to-clients for details.